# Replace White-space with hyphen then create URL

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

I'm trying to speed up a process of webscraping by sending raw data to python in lieu of correctly formatted data.

Current data is received as an excel file with data formatted as:

**26 EXAMPLE RD EXAMPLEVILLE SA 5000**

Data is formatted in excel via macros to:

- Replace all spaces with hyphen
- Change all text to lower-case
- Paste text onto end of http://example.com/property/

Formatted data is **http://www.example.com/property/26-example-rd-exampleville-sa-5000**

What i'm trying to accomplish:

Get python to go into excel sheet and follow formatting rules listed above, then pass the records to the scraper.

Here is the code I have been trying to compile - please go easy i am VERY new.

Any advice or reading sources related to python formatting would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import csv
from lxml import html
import xlrd

# URL_BUILDER
# Source File for UNFORMATTED DATA

file_location = "C:\Python27\Projects\REA_SCRAPER\NewScraper\ScrapeFile.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('((PythonScraperDNC))')

# REA_SCRAPER
# Pass Data from URL_BUILDER to URL_LIST []

URL_LIST = []

# Search Phrase to capture suitable URL's for Scraping

text2search = \
'''<p class="property-value__title">
RECENTLY SOLD
</p>'''

# Write Sales .CSV file

with open('Results.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
for (index, url) in enumerate(URL_LIST):
page = requests.get(url)
print '<Scanning Url For Sale>'

if text2search in page.text:
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
(title, ) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
(price, ) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//div[@class="property-value__price"]'))
(sold, ) = (x.text_content().strip() for x intree.xpath('//p[@class="property-value__agent"]'))

writer.writerow([title, price, sold])
else:
writer.writerow(['No Sale'])
```

Comment: As you can probably see from the syntax highlighting here, you're missing a double quote at the end of the `file_location =` line. Fix that first and then tell us the exact problem you're having. ("It doesn't work," or the like doesn't count.)

Comment: You also have some indentation errors toward the end. Make sure the code you share here is exactly what you're running.

Comment: @smarx Thanks for the formatting advice - I've used SO A few times now and still trying to learn the best way to post code - IE do i delete all white spaces prior to posting - then hit CRTL - K or leave my existing indenting from atom & then hit CTRL - K

Comment: Paste your exact code (including indentation). Then highlight and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: @smarx - Thank you, i'll follow that moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to figure out how to do the formatting in Python:

```
text = '26 EXAMPLE RD EXAMPLEVILLE SA 5000'
url = 'http://example.com/property/' + text.replace(' ', '-').lower()
print(url)

# Output:
# http://example.com/property/26-example-rd-exampleville-sa-5000
```

Comment: Pretty much nailed it, however I need to do it 2000+ times from a list in excel then pass formatted URL to my scraper - what you have pasted above will get me started though so thank you!